# Converting a CSV file data to edges and nodes for GNN

Tags: python, graph, graph-neural-network

What is the best way to convert the following dataset to graph representation? The aim to predict Rate of Prediction (ROP) using GNN since its a regression problem.

I have a dataset with 7293 rows. First 3 entries are as follows:

```
ROP(1 m)    Depth(m)    weight on bit (kg)  Rotary Speed (rpm)  Pump Press (KPa)    Temp In(degC)   Flow In(liters/min) Flow Out %
  17.31       25.96             0.0              151.09             3197.35            32.71            4200.22            101.61

  18.63       26.27             0.0              151.09             3168.46            32.68            4195.6             101.7

   5.66       26.59             0.0               61.54             3134.26            32.73            4174.82            96.81
```

I have also calculated the importance of each parameter with the ROP as follows:

```
Predictors           Pearson Correlation between ROP (m/h) and Predictors
Depth (m)                                    −0.508247
Weight on Bit (kg)                           −0.523441
Rotary Speed (rpm)                            0.28907
Pump Press (KPa)                             −0.49319
Temp In (degC)                               −0.221713
Flow In (liters/min)                          0.481607
Flow Out %                                   −0.116068
```

`Nodes` is going to be the ROP

`Node Features` is going to be the predictor's values

`Edges` I will assume that each node is connected to each parameter

`Edge Weights` These will be the pearson correlation values

**I haven't shared my code since it doesn't give me anything meaningful**